# Like a Facebook Page Programmatically

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I search google for this problem but I didn't  understand answer I found.
Actually I want to Like page grammatically like I can post a message on Page behalf of user.
I have Long term access token getting it from my app.

I have an android app where user can login through facebook account and that time I asked user for the Post permission of facebook.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented simple library which allows you to add Facebook 'Like' button easy:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.8'
}
```

Read [more details here](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html).

The simplest way to add like button:

```
<com.shamanland.facebook.likebutton.FacebookLikeButton
    style="@style/Widget.FacebookLikeButton"
    app:pageUrl="http://url.to.like/page.html"
    app:pageTitle="Title of page"
    app:pageText="Short description of page"
    app:pagePictureUrl="http://url.to.like/picture.jpg"
    />
```

This view will be drawn in your layout: [image]

After clicking on it you will see the dialog with official Facebook 'Like' plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the Facebook SDK for the Android it is only possible to Share something not to Like. if you want to Like page you should use WebView and use Iframe in it to display like button.

Comment: Is there anything like feed option available in facebook.Where just add message and access token and pageid where message going to post.